# ¿cómo asignar 5 estrellas en un RatingBar?

Tags: android

Estaba diseñando una interfaz, y me encontraba con el siguiente problema:

estoy integrando el componente `ratingBar` a una de mis activities, y cuando traté de asignarle el número de estrellas máximas en 5 con la propiedad `numStars`, la aplicación coloca el número de estrellas que quiere, ignorando la cantidad que yo le indiqué.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi `ratingBar` respete el número de estrellas que le estoy indicando?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, la documentación dice lo siguiente respecto a la propiedad `numStars` de `ratingbar`:

> coloca en número de estrellas a mostrar. Para que estos se muestren correctamente, se recomienda que el ancho de este componente sea `wrap content`.

entonces, teniendo esto en cuenta, el XML de mi `ratingBar` quedó así:

```
<RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

en el cual, la propiedad `numStars` indica que sólo se pondrán 5 estrellas, `stepSize` indica en cuanto se "parte" la estrella, colocándolo en `.5`, sólo puedes seleccionar media estrella, o la estrella completa.

Answer (score 3):

En la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) indica usar como ancho `wrap_content`,

> El número de estrellas establecidas a través de [setNumStars(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setNumStars(int)) o
>   mediante la propiedad en el xml `android:numStars`, se mostrará cuando
>   el ancho de diseño se establezca en `wrap_content` (si se establece
>   otro ancho de diseño, los resultados pueden ser impredecibles).

pero puedes usar un ancho mayor personalizable para que se muestren todas las estrellas.

La propiedad [**android:numStars**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android:numStars) indica cuantas estrellas aparecen:

```
android:numStars="5"
```

La propiedad  [**android:rating**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android:rating) indica como se llenaran as estrellas por default:

```
android:rating="3.5"
```

La propiedad [**android:stepSize**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android:stepSize) indica el tamaño del paso.

```
android:stepSize="0.5"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, en realidad tu explicación es correcta, así como tu respuesta, es cierto lo que comenta la documentación solo que también puede determinarse un ancho mayor en la vista para que se desplieguen las estrellas sin problemas.